# Do not return error since i expect null

Tags: c#

Here i have example of getting inventory from json string.

`inventory = JsonUtility.FromJson<InventoryModel>GFile.GetPlayer(FileComponent.PlayerInventory));`

Since i am loading that string from file it is possible it is just blank and i want to first check if it is blank and i would do it like this:

```
if(GFile.GetPlayer(FileComponent.PlayerInventory) != " ")
{
    inventory = JsonUtility.FromJson<InventoryModel>(GFile.GetPlayer(FileComponent.PlayerInventory));
}
```

So my question is if there is any more elegant way of doing this instead of typing if statement like this?

Comment: assign to variable and check if variable is null?

Comment: I think the way you are doing is good enough and easier to understand

Comment: @AmrElgarhy : statement GFile.GetPlayer(FileComponent.PlayerInventory) is executed twice in this case. If file is big then we could definitely improve on performance by eliminating duplicate call to read file.

Comment: @PankajKapare yes, you are right, and now the way you have in your updated answer is much better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest

```
string data = GFile.GetPlayer(FileComponent.PlayerInventory);
if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(data))
{
    inventory = JsonUtility.FromJson<InventoryModel>(data);
}
```

This way you only call GetPlayer once, and it doesn't matter if the resulting data is an empty string or is full of whitespace - it still won't enter that block and set inventory.

**Edit**

For older versions of .Net, this will also work

```
string data = GFile.GetPlayer(FileComponent.PlayerInventory);
if(data != null && data.Trim().Length == 0)
{
    inventory = JsonUtility.FromJson<InventoryModel>(data);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally submitted it before I was done. This will only run GetPlayer once.

Comment: Are you on .Net 4.0 or higher? If not, give me a second and I'll update my answer for lower versions of .Net

Comment: For some reason i can not see function `IsNullOrWhiteSpaced`

Answer (score 3):

Why not like this? :

```
var player = GFile.GetPlayer(FileComponent.PlayerInventory);
if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(player)) {
    inventory = JsonUtility.FromJson<InventoryModel>(player);
}
```

Comment: Isnt it good idea to check file contents first and pass it to jsonutility only when its not null or empty?

Comment: I can't since at inventory assigning that value it drops me error that Json is empty

Comment: I would expect `var myTempVar= GFile.GetPlayer(FileComponent.PlayerInventory);` and then `inventory = JsonUtility.FromJson<InventoryModel>(myTempVar);` from OP's description. Notice how his `if` block evaluates something different than the value that is later assigned to `inventory`.

Comment: He want to assign a value to inventory just if GFile.GetPlayer(FileComponent.PlayerInventory) != " " , so your way could raise an exception or not right from the logic flow point of view.

Comment: I have edited my answer because you basically changed your question